# Pls help me stop this bitcoin

Tags: blockchain

https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=1AeRh3hBFCCouBukF3NrxtHjar1aBQToh4&format=html

help me stop it or tell me how i can stop it

Final Balance   $ 18.58

Comment: Your transaction has 3 confirmations already. At this point, stopping the transaction is considered effectively impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Please do note, you can not terminate any transactions on blockchain that has confirmations. As i can see there is 64 confirmations now. So it can not be stopped.